# Java array compariosn

Tags: java, arrays

I want to compare current elements of an array with its previous elements using for loop.
For example i have an array which has elements 1,2,3 and next time it will have elements 1,3,4 and third time it has elements 1,5,6 and so on so every time i want to compare array elemets like 1,2,3 compare 1,3,4 and then 1,3,4 compare 1,5,6

```
public class test {

   int[] temp=null;
   int depth_data_count=0;

   public void onDepthFrameEvent(short[] depth_frame, byte[] player_index, float[] XYZ, float[] UV) {
      compare_depth_data(XYZ);
   }

   public void compare_depth_data(float[] depth_data) {
      if(depth_data_count==0) {
         temp=new float[depth_data.length]; temp = depth_data.clone(); 
      } 
      for(int i=0;i<depth_data.length;i++) { 
         if (depth_data[i]>temp[i]) { /* ..... */ } } 
      }
   }   
}
```

I am getting latest values of array in this compare_depth_data function.
I have created a global array temp and checking that if its first time then save the data to this temporary array and compare each and every element...i am not getting an idea what to do for the 2nd time

Comment: Besides creating the method declaration, what else have you tried to do?

Comment: if(depth_data_count==0)
 {
  temp=new float[depth_data.length];
  temp = depth_data.clone();
 }
 for(int i=0;i<depth_data.length;i++)
 {
  if(depth_data[i]>temp[i])
  {
   
  }
 }

Comment: Because arrays won't save previous variables, save them elsewhere.

Comment: I have created a global array temp and checking that if its first time then save the data to this temporary array and compare each and every element...i am not getting an idea what to do for the 2nd time

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

Why are you trying to wrongfuly cast to float an integer, to assign it as float to an integer array? you are hitting "incompatible types". I suggest you to start using an IDE.

Your integer "temp" is of type integer.
.length is a variable int.
Just assign it.

If you want to compare two arrays, with one of them changing every time, you need to have 2 array structures. First one will be recording the previous values, and the second one will be used as the new one to be compared with.